# Error: Command failed with exit code 1: ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I am having this error when I do `npx prisma db seed`

code:

> 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
> '/run/media/.../myapp/prisma/imaginaryUncacheableRequireResolveScript'
> ] }
>
> An error occured while running the seed command: Error: Command failed
> with exit code 1: ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"}
> prisma/seed.ts

I have this in Package.json

```
      "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake by me the file should be named seed.ts not seeds.ts